# position overlay div in css/js

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

good people -
a js & css Q:
I have here a timeline, with an overlay. The positioning of the information-box that pops up is my problem. 
http://dev.favouritesystems.com/appslist/
it has position absolute, and I wonder how I can get it relative to content not screen? geddit?
any hints appreciated.

Comment: This is a Wordpress plugin, can you specify which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the outer wrapper to relative, and keep the information-box as absolute. That way it will be absolute to the wrapper and not the body.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `position:relative` for your `#wrapper` then the popup will be positioned absolute according its parent

Comment: thanks, sotiris, you guys in here are too quick :-) much appreciated.